# Skipping entry with js files in WebPack

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-frontend

I have to use Webpack for one of my projects to build front-end bundles for js, css and other static assets. It does the job well, but in my early stages of the project I've got only some css and static images and no js files yet. Here is my full `webpack.config.js`

```
const Webpack = require("webpack");
const Glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const configurator = {
    entries: function(){
        var entries = {
            application: [
                './assets/dummy.js',
            ],
        }

        return entries
    },

    plugins() {
        var plugins = [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{from: "./assets",to: ""}], {copyUnmodified: true,ignore: ["css/**", "js/**", "**.js"] }),
        ];

        return plugins
    },

    moduleOptions: function() {
        return {
            rules: [

            ]
        }
    },

    buildConfig: function(){
        const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

        var config = {
            mode: env,
            entry: configurator.entries(),
            output: {filename: "[name].[hash].js", path: `${__dirname}/public/assets`},
            plugins: configurator.plugins(),
            module: configurator.moduleOptions()
        }

       return config
    }
}

module.exports = configurator.buildConfig()
```

Practically what it does for me is copying assets to public dir. I don't have any javascripts yet, but they will be in the future. So, I tried commenting `entry`, setting it to null or empty string with no luck. It seems Webpack needs to process js files so badly. My current solution is creating an empty `dummy.js` file and feeding it to Webpack. Annoyingly it generates some 3.3kb `application.afff4a3748b8d5d33a3a.js` file with some boilerplate js code, despite that my source js file is totally empty.

I understand that this is an edge use case for Webpack and Webpack was primarily created for processing javascript, but I bet many people still use it not just for bundling javascripts. So, my question, is there a better, more elegant way to skip bundling js files in Webpack?

p.s.

I think, I've found a related question without an answer here [How to make WebPack copy a library instead of bundling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938888/how-to-make-webpack-copy-a-library-instead-of-bundling)

p.s.#2

The suggested duplicate question has an accepted answer with an invalid Webpack config `Invalid configuration object.`, so, I can't use it to solve my issue.
Moreover, the answer reads

> webpack will create a dummy javascript file

and I'm specifically asking how to avoid creating unnecessary files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I build sass/less/css in webpack without requiring them in my JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780585/can-i-build-sass-less-css-in-webpack-without-requiring-them-in-my-js)

Comment: sorry, no luck, that answer doesn't work at all